# Flutter test - verifying assets exist

Tags: testing, flutter, assets

I have a flutter app which contains a large list of quotes, each with an associated audio file.

I've written a simple test that verifies all the specified audio files are where they're supposed to be, in case of typos etc:

```
test('specified audio file should exist for all quotes', () {
    ALL_QUOTES.forEach((quote) {
      final expectedPath = 'assets/${quote.filename}.wav';
      final exists = new File(expectedPath).existsSync();
      expect(exists, isTrue, reason: '$expectedPath does not exist');
    });
  });
```

This passes fine in IntelliJ, however running from the command line using `flutter test` it fails on the first thing it looks for.

Is there a way of doing this which will work regardless of how it's run? Why does it pass one way but not the other?

Comment: Off-topic, but an alternate solution would be to use code-generation to generate such `ALL_QUOTES` from your assets

Comment: Normally I'd go down that sort of a route, but unfortunately in this case there's additional metadata associated to each quote such as additional search terms, what the "source" of it is (e.g. the name of the TV show) and an image asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I got to the bottom of this, and it *is* something you can do in a unit test.

To diagnose, I added the line `print(Directory.current);` to the test. Running in IntelliJ, I get `/home/project_name`. From the command line, it's `/home/project_name/test`. So just a simple file path thing to resolve.

*Edited to include Ovidiu's simpler logic for getting the right asset path*

```
void main() {
  test('specified audio file should exist for all quotes', () {
    ALL_QUOTES.forEach((quote) {
      final expectedPath = 'assets/${quote.filename}.wav';
      final exists = _getProjectFile(expectedPath).existsSync();
      expect(exists, isTrue, reason: '$expectedPath does not exist');
    });
  });
}

File _getProjectFile(String path) {
  final String assetFolderPath = Platform.environment['UNIT_TEST_ASSETS'];
  return File('$assetFolderPath/$path');
}
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it was not accurate. I got things mixed up - the `AssetManifest.json` file is not available to Unit and Widget tests by default, but the actual assets are still available and can be accessed directly. Also, here's a somewhat cleaner way to get the asset folder path, which works for Unit and Widget tests: `final String assetFolderPath = Platform.environment['UNIT_TEST_ASSETS'];`

Comment: That doesn't work for me, because that's the directory for the unit test assets. In this case, I'm wanting a test which performs some verification on the real assets used by the actual app.

Comment: From my experience those are the same - there is no such thing as unit test assets, as far as I know. It's just that the assets are moved to a different directory (or at least have a different relative path) as part of the unit & widget tests, which is what the variable I mentioned above helps with.

Comment: Yep, you're right - I'd just plugged it in wrong. Much simpler, thanks!